# How to make button visible only after viewpager page loaded completly?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am new in view pager.i have 2 pages in view pager..each contain button..i want show button after page fully loaded.Now button is showing half scrolling it self..

```
class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private List<Fragment> fragments;

        public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
            super(fm);
            this.fragments = fragments;
        }
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return this.fragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return this.fragments.size();
        }

        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }
```

adding page

```
 pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(activity.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
        viewpager.setId(position);
         viewpager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
```

fragment:

```
public class secondclass extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_secondclass, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
```

please help me..

Answer (score 0):

Just use `OnPageChangeListener`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to do some tedious tasks for this to be done.
First your activity containing the viewpager should have a way to communicate with the fragments of the viewpager. once you are done with this.

Then set OnPageChangeListener on the viewpager
and one of the overridden callback methods would be the following one

```
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
               // you know the position now. send the message to the fragment at this position to show the button or do any particular task
        }
```

you are all set to go

In viewpager nearby fragments are loaded even before they are actually visible to the user, this is done so as to provide a smooth scrolling effect.
So onCreateView and onResume methods of the second fragment is already called...even before the user scrolls to the second page.
So to do something exactly when the user loads a page completely we need to user the onPageSelected method and with the help of the position argument we notify the fragment at that position to do the tasks.
In your case show the button...so you need to set visibility of the button INVISIBLE in the layout and make it visible when the page is selected.

For the above thing to work your activity needs to have a reference to the fragment...or you may request the viewpageradapter to provide you the reference by doing a bit caching of the current fragment...apply any logic of yours.

Assume all your fragments are of type MyFragment and have a method doVisibleTask to make the button visible AND getItem of your view pager adapter returns the same instance everytime for a particular position.
you could do the following

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
// get the reference to the fragment
MyFragment mf = (MyFragment)viewPagerAdapter.getItem(position);
mf.m=doVisibleTask();
// you know the position now. send the message to the fragment at this position to show the button or do any particular task
}
```